# How to deal with "negative length vectors are not allowed" for R input

Tags: r

I want to input a stata version data set (`sample.dta`) with almost 60000 SNPs information (as columns) in to R. This data set was created with SAS. I used the code:

```
data <- read.dta("sample.dta")
```

But it doesn't work and the error message is:

> "Error in read.dta("sample.dta") : negative length vectors are not allowed".

But when I try another data set with no more than 25000 SNPs, it works.

So I don't know whether some people have been faced with similar problem? 
And what is the exact reason for this error? And how do you deal with it before?

I really hope the experts in R could help me figure out it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could be a memory problem? How much memory do you have, and what is the expected size of the overall data? Perhaps you can extrapolate from the 'working' 25K SNP data set?

Comment: Sometimes reader functions fail for opaque reasons; you might try `haven::read_dta` to see if it works or gives you a more useful error message.

Comment: I never used sas or sas datasets, but you could divide your dataset of 60.000 SNPs to 2 datasets of 30.000 SNPs each, and bind them together in R.  Probably it would help.

Comment: Hi Gopala, It may not due to the memory limit. I run it in the server of the University. And there are at least 16 g memory.

Comment: Hi Alistaire, I know that R package, but when I use that one, I always get some unexpected missing. So I choose this route now. Thanks.

Comment: I will try last suggestion, thank you